# Окно на переднем плане во время звонка - Delphi +Firemonkey + Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Во время звонка в службе есть Broadcast receiver, который обрабатывает входящие и исходящие звонки. Определяет номер.

Но пользователю во время звонка нужно показать какое-нибудь заметное, но небольшое окно с картинкой и текстом, чуть больше, чем toast. Окно, которое будет висеть некоторое время впереди перед звонилкой.

Сейчас реализовано так, что служба показывает Toast, но этого недостаточно, т.к. это маленькое текстовое и краткосрочное сообщение. Пока пользователь достанет смартфон из кармана, потом из чехла или пока откроет переднюю крышку чехла, toast пропадает.

Нужно что-то типа Toast. Но чтобы висело секунд 10-15.

Как вариант, можно было бы показывать Notification, но и здесь Андроид и Firemonkey добавляют свои ограничения: вверху, в строке статуса отображается только значок и только главный значок приложения.

Попытался менять главную иконку у приложения перед показом Notification, но всё равно отображается стандартная.

Да и текста нет :(, нельзя в статус баре показать свой текст, даже временно.

Если будут примеры, буду весьма признателен.